# Selenium + Python opening chrome with session password

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to open chrome browser with password session in python3 and Selenium
Here is my code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

options = Options();
options.add_argument(r"--user-data-dir=/home/username/.config/google-chrome/")
options.add_argument(r'--profile-directory=User Profile')
service = Service('/opt/google/chrome/chromedriver')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
```

It's open my chrome with my profile but delete all cookie and password connection.

How i can open chrome with my saved password and session ?

Answer (score 0):

You're using linux, try undetected chromedriver as webdriver

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).